# Is it problematic to use a caching mechanism for throttling?

Tags: c#, azure, caching, azure-webjobs, memorycache

I implemented a throttling mechanism on our Azure web job. The "job" of our web job is to download separate .wav files from a 3rd party api constantly throughout the day. And it does this around 5,000 times a day (right now). However, the 3rd party api has usage restrictions, and only allows us to download a maximum of 10 wav files every 60 seconds. If we go over that, we get a 429 error for every request for the next 60 seconds.

So I implemented a little code to throttle our requests to this api. This is the block of code that now gets executed before every request:

```
        var maxPerPeriod = 10;
        var keyPrefix = RingCentralId;
        var intervalPeriod = 60000;
        var sleepInterval = 5000;
        var recentTransactions = MemoryCache.Default.Count(x => x.Key.StartsWith(keyPrefix));
        while (recentTransactions >= maxPerPeriod)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepInterval);
            recentTransactions = MemoryCache.Default.Count(x => x.Key.StartsWith(keyPrefix));
        }
        var key = keyPrefix + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        var existing = MemoryCache.Default.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith(key));
        if (existing != null && existing.Any())
        {
            var counter = 2;
            var last = existing.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Last();
            var pieces = last.Key.Split('_');
            if (pieces.Count() > 2)
            {
                var lastCount = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(pieces[2], out lastCount))
                {
                    counter = lastCount + 1;
                }
            }
            key = key + "_" + counter;
        }
        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(intervalPeriod)
        };
        MemoryCache.Default.Set(key, 1, policy);
```

And this actually works beautifully (at least for now). As you can see, I am using the cache with unique keys that last for 60 seconds each. This mechanism searches the cache, and if there are 10 or more currently in the cache, then that means that we need to wait until they expire. And I do this by implementing a `while` loop. And that's the part that has me the most concerned. I don't have a lot of experience using the `MemoryCache`. Am I possibly introducing an infinite loop at some point in time? Is there anything else that I could be overlooking that might cause issues, especially if we scale up to, say 1,000,000 requests per day?

Comment: Wouldn't a simple timer make if far less complicated?

Comment: That's a good thought. However, we want this to run as fast as we possibly can. If we use a timer, we would have to have a hard-coded interval, probably set at 60 seconds, for each individual wav file to run. That's going to cause our processing to possibly run 6x slower (60 seconds compared to 10 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to have more than one instance of the WebJob doing the work, why not use a TimerTrigger and space your calls out evenly?

[Here's the link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/README.md#timertrigger) to the documentation.

Comment: I have not heard of a timer trigger. I'll have to investigate.

Comment: I've included a link to the docs. It's super-easy to use and will call a method that you specify on a set schedule.

Comment: Yes, and you can also just specify the App Service as being Always On, and include a settings.job file with a 'schedule' element. This will do the same thing if your job is a continuous one.